# MySQL Wordpress Product Pricing Update from a remote database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to pull the wordpress/woocommerce pricing from the clients erp database. I have a wordpress (woocommerce) database with pricing for selling products online.  The wordpress MySQL database stores the price in a meta table:  wp_database.wp_postmeta.meta_key="_price" wp_database.wp_postmeta.meta_value=1.99.

I have a thousands products and i need to update all of them daily from a different MySQL database: erp_database.part.new_price

The unique ID is: erp_database.part.ID and in the wordpress db its wp_database.wp_postmeta.meta_key="_sku"

Can this be done in one query?

Here's wp_database sample data would look like (but 1000s records and dozens of keys):

[image]

And here is what erp_database look like:

[image]

this is getting close but i think the first WHERE clause should be an IN instead of a SELECT.  Anyone know how to do this?

```
UPDATE `wp_database`.wm_postmeta AS existing,
 erp_database.part AS newpricing
SET existing.pm_postmeta.meta_value =(
    SELECT
        newpricing.new_price
    FROM
        newpricing
    WHERE
        newpricing.ID =(
            SELECT
                existing.meta_value
            WHERE
                existing.meta_key = "_sku"
        )
)
```

closer?

```
UPDATE `wp_database`.wm_postmeta AS existing,
 erp_database.part AS newpricing
SET existing.pm_postmeta.meta_value =(
    SELECT
        newpricing.NEW_PRICE
    FROM
        newpricing
    WHERE
        newpricing.ID =(
            SELECT
                existing.meta_value,
                existing.meta_value as newprice

            WHERE
                existing.meta_key = "_sku" and existing.post_id = newprice.post_id
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, i got it myself!!!!  And to all the others out there that have to update an entire woocommerce store from a list, spreadsheet, or external ERP database, here's the jist of it:

```
UPDATE pm_postmeta as t,
(
SELECT
a.meta_key AS id_key,
a.meta_value AS id_value,
b.meta_key AS price_key,
b.meta_value AS price_value,
a.meta_id,
a.post_id,
erp_database.part.ID,
erp_database.part.price AS "Price"
FROM
`wp_database`.pm_postmeta AS a
INNER JOIN `wp_database`.pm_postmeta AS b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
INNER JOIN erp_database.part ON a.meta_value LIKE concat("%",erp_database.part.ID,"%")
WHERE
a.meta_key = "_sku" AND
b.meta_key = "_price" 

ORDER BY
b.post_id ASC
limit 100 ) as thetemp
SET meta_value = thetemp.`Price` WHERE meta_key="_price" and t.post_id = thetemp.post_id
```

of course as you all know ,there are a couple more places you have to update price, and delete cache...